# how to use number in CHICKEN scheme script parameter

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Here is my scheme code:

```
(define (fact n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
(define (main args)
  (fact (car args)))
```

Then i run this code as a script with this command in bash:

`csi -ss test.scm 4`

However, the interpreter get this error message:

```
Error: (=) bad argument type: "4"

Call history:

<syntax>      (##core#lambda (n) (define (iter num result) (if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* result num)))) ...
<syntax>      [fact2] (##core#let ((iter (##core#undefined))) (##core#set! iter (##core#lambda (num result) (if (> num n) ...
<syntax>      [fact2] (##core#begin (##core#set! iter (##core#lambda (num result) (if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* ...
<syntax>      [fact2] (##core#set! iter (##core#lambda (num result) (if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* result num))))...
<syntax>      [fact2] (##core#lambda (num result) (if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* result num))))
<syntax>      [iter] (##core#begin (##core#if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* result num))))
<syntax>      [iter] (##core#if (> num n) result (iter (+ num 1) (* result num)))
<syntax>      [iter] (> num n)
<syntax>      [iter] (iter (+ num 1) (* result num))
<syntax>      [iter] (+ num 1)
<syntax>      [iter] (* result num)
<syntax>      [fact2] (iter 1 1)
<syntax>      [fact2] (##core#undefined)
<eval>    [main] (fact (car args))
<eval>    [main] (car args)
<eval>    [fact] (= n 1)    <--
```

I guess the interpreter take the argument 4 as a string, so how to use number in CHICKEN scheme script parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [string->number](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard#numerical-input-and-output), which is a standard R5RS procedure:

```
(define (main args)
  (fact (string->number (car args))))
```